# How to get the data from firebase realtime database in react js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to get the the data from firebase(realtime database). I refered various videos but I didn't get the proper solution. I don't know where I made a mistake. I share my code and firebase screenshot.

I want to show this firebase data in table form on frontend.

here as screenshot of firebase realtime database.

[image]

My Code is:

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
function TableDataGet() {
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
//firebase get table datacode
}})
 return (
<div>
      <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>nameMarathi</th>
                    <th>srno</th>
                    <th>mobile</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {
                   DataUser.map((item,id)=>{
                       <div>
                           {item.name}
                       </div>
                   })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>


 )
}
export default TableDataGet
```

Comment: I mean, if you Google it there's like 1,000 tutorials on Firebase+React real time data UIs, what _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: Assuming that you didn't take out any code, you've got a ways to go... I'd recommend what Jayce444 said and try to follow a tutorial... and while it doesn't exacly address the issue, if you're trying to decide between the realtime database and firestore, Firestore is newer and recommended (and realtime as well) Best of luck!

Comment: i just want the code to get the data only in realtime.

Comment: inside useEffect hook i am writing following code. but its not working, i get only id of data but not get name.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            const dbRef=ref(db)
        get(child(dbRef,"userdataRecord")).then((snapshot)=>{
            var DataUser=[];
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot=>{
                DataUser.push(childSnapshot.val())
            })
            TableDataGet(DataUser)
        })
        }
    }, [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the query of get data from Firebase Realtime Database.

```
      let ref = database.ref("/buyers");
      ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.val()
      console.log(data)
      })
```